# Sort dictionary by multiple keys

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have myDict in the format of:

```
{
  data1 = { 
             key1 = abc
             key2 = abc
             key3 = abc
             key4 = abc
          },
  data2 = { 
             key1 = abc
             key2 = abc
             key3 = abc
             key4 = abc
          }
  ..
}
```

I use the following code to sort myDict and get the the sorted data by keys.

```
    sortedArr = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:
                 ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* obj1, NSDictionary* obj2)
                 {
                     NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
                     if(obj1[@"key1"] != nil && obj2[@"key1"]!=nil)
                     {
                         return [obj2[@"key1"] compare:obj1[@"key1"]];
                     }
                     else
                         return result;
                 }];
```

sortedArr:

```
(data1,data2,data3,...)
```

question is how do i sort myDict using 2 keys instead of one because I face an issue if key1 value are the same, then i want it to be sorted by key2.

Comment: `result = [obj2[@"key1"] compare:obj1[@"key1"]]; if (result != NSOrderedSame){return result;}else{result = [obj2[@"key2"] compare:obj1[@"key2"]];}` and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to account for the case for each key where the comparison returns `NSOrderedSame`. You can iterate the keys like this:

```
NSArray *allKeys = @[@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", ...];
for (NSString *aKey in allKeys)
{
    if(obj1[aKey] != nil && obj2[aKey] != nil)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [obj2[aKey] compare:obj1[aKey]]; 
        if (result != NSOrderedSame) return result;
    }
}
return NSOrderedSame;
```

<sub>This answer is substantially different from my original answer, all credit to [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) for this solution</sub>

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the question, it's not about one of the value is nil, but if they are the same. If `[obj2[@"key1"] compare:obj1[@"key1"]] == NSOrderedSame` user wants to be ordered according to key2.

Comment: `for (NSString *aKey in allKeys){if(obj1[aKey] != nil && obj2[aKey]!=nil){NSComparisonResult result = [obj2[aKey] compare:obj1[aKey]]; if (result != NSOrderedSame) return result;}}return NSOrderedSame;}];` should do the trick then, where `NSArray *allKeys = @[@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", ...];` is declared before the block.

Comment: Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll delete mine! I was just writing something similar, but seems unfair that I get the credit for your solution.

Comment: It's okay. I'm clearly no here for the points, but to help, and resolve mini-puzzles.

Comment: I also got my answer from Larme's comment ytd. But I guess I'll accept this answer. Thanks both of u. Have a nice day. :D

Comment: I just remembered about community wiki, so have done that with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert nil into collections (dictionaries, arrays, index sets, etc).

You can, however, insert [NSNull null] into them as this is what they made it for

Below you can find the code which sorts the first level dictionaries by all keys within subDictinaries.

```
NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSMutableDictionary *data1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[data1 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key1"];
[data1 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key2"];
[data1 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key3"];
[data1 setObject:@"a" forKey:@"key4"];

NSMutableDictionary *data2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[data2 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key1"];
[data2 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key2"];
[data2 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key3"];
[data2 setObject:@"b" forKey:@"key4"];

NSMutableDictionary *data3 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[data3 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key1"];
[data3 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key2"];
[data3 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"key3"];
[data3 setObject:@"c" forKey:@"key4"];

[md setObject:data1 forKey:@"data1"];
[md setObject:data2 forKey:@"data2"];
[md setObject:data3 forKey:@"data3"];

NSArray *allKeys = @[@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", @"key4"];

NSArray *sortedData = [md keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

    for (NSString *key in allKeys) {

        if (obj1[key] != nil && obj2[key] != nil) { // Checking if both keys exist

            NSComparisonResult result = [obj2[key] compare:obj1[key]];

            if (result != NSOrderedSame) {

                return result;

            }

        } else { // One of keys is missing

            return NSOrderedSame;

        }

    }

    return NSOrderedSame; // No keys

}];

NSLog(@"%@", sortedData);
```

Output:

(
    data3,
    data2,
    data1
)

Comment: By comparing with `nil`, we assume that the author check that BOTH dictionary have a value/key for the tested key to be "allowed to compare". For instance `NSDictionary *d1 = @{@"key15":@"value15"}` vs `NSDictionary *d2 = @{@"key4":@"value4"}` `d1[@"key1"]` should returns `nil`.